# Flutter Bloc not rebuilding after

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Bloc not weirdly not updating the ui even though I can see the internals did update. WHen I add to the state `Set<String>` I do get a rebuild. but at remove I don't get a rebuild.

My state

```
part of 'global_loading_bloc.dart';

class GlobalLoadingState extends Equatable {
   GlobalLoadingState({subscriptions})
      : subscriptions = subscriptions ?? {};
  final Set<String> subscriptions;

  GlobalLoadingState copyWith({Set<String>? subscriptions}) {
    return GlobalLoadingState(
      subscriptions: subscriptions ?? this.subscriptions,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [subscriptions];
}
```

The Bloc

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:julie_food/blocs/get_it.dart';
import 'package:julie_food/core/services/models/order.dart';

part 'global_loading_event.dart';
part 'global_loading_state.dart';

class GlobalLoadingBloc extends Bloc<GlobalLoadingEvent, GlobalLoadingState> {
  GlobalLoadingBloc() : super(GlobalLoadingState()) {
    

    on<AddOrder>((event, emit) async {
      // add to Set to look like {'bruh'}
      emit(state.copyWith(subscriptions: state.subscriptions..add(event.key)));
      try {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
        // remove to set to look like {}
        emit(state.copyWith(
            subscriptions: state.subscriptions..remove(event.key)));
        
        event.onSuccess();
        // printing here shows that the state did recieve update
        
      } catch (error) {
        print('delay done ${state.subscriptions}');
        emit(state.copyWith(
            subscriptions: state.subscriptions..remove(event.key)));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

WIdget Builder

```
BlocBuilder<GlobalLoadingBloc, GlobalLoadingState>(
                    bloc: globalLoadingBloc,
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      print(state.subscriptions); // I dont get a rebuild at remove
                      return ContainerLoadingButton(
                          background: primaryRedColor4,
                          text: 'Order now',
                          loading: state.subscriptions
                              .contains('createOrder-${widget.meal!.mealName}'),
                          onTap: () async {
                            
                            globalLoadingBloc.add(AddOrder(
                                key: 'createOrder-${widget.meal!.mealName}',
                                order: _order!,
                                onSuccess: OnOrderSuccess
                                ));
                          });
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Mutating the Set here:

```
// remove to set to look like {}
emit(state.copyWith(
   subscriptions: state.subscriptions..remove(event.key)));
```

Therefore the set is still the same instance and the bloc does not re-render.

Try using Set.Where to remove the value:

```dart
emit(state.copyWith(
   subscriptions: state.subscriptions.where((item) => item != event.key)).toSet();
```

Comment: The first part is actually correct but the last one(Set.where) is off. 1st doesn't return list, 2nd doesn't remove from set. this the actual answer `Set.of(state.subscriptions)..remove(event.key)`. kindly update the answer.

Comment: Sorry I missed the ".toSet()" off the end. But other than that I'm not sure what you mean? the second code snippet returns a new set that only contains the items that you want to keep. Its the same as removing one and is a very common pattern in dart and typescript when working with immutable objects. Try the following in dart pad: 

final items = {1,2,3,4,5};
 final newItems = items.where((item) => item != 1).toSet();
  print(newItems);